# Upload File with Related Extension Filter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problems on my upload page. When I try to upload file, the extension that can be selected set by "all type", but I've tried to set my allowed type config to jpg. This is my controller :

```
public function upload_file($noArsip)
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/arsip/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg'; // --> how to make the allowed type only image extension?

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('video');

        $data_upload_files = $this->upload->data();
        //proses database

        $image = $data_upload_files['file_name'];

        $data = array(
                'video'=>$image
                );

        $this->daftar_arsip_m->updateData($noArsip,$data);
        //$this->load->view("upload_foto_v", $data);
        redirect('upload_foto');

    }
```

i dont want to use validation when the file is selected, i just want it to filter the file for the related extension, like image or video related type. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate extensions by `|`

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
```

**PS**: Extensions are not case sensitive, codeigniter will take care of Upper case formats.

[**Reference**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

To filter the browse window, just add  `accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png"` as attribute to the `input` tag.

Example:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png">
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6J2jV/)**

Comment: thanks for your response. i already tried that but it will work if user already select the file. i just want that the file will be automatically filtered when user choose the file when uploading. is it possible?

Comment: not working.. the other extension still can be selected

Comment: @RezaKahfi if you are talking about selecting all files, then i dont think it is possible to remove it. But now you can filter the files by choosimg the image extension. Also you can use accept="image/*" to accept all image types

Comment: sorry, my fault.. i opened the wrong view, because this is my friend's by the way.. thank you so much for your help